# flexbox Расположение друг под другом

Tags: css, flexbox

Мне надо сделать, чтобы блоки, чьи высоты не превышают самых высоких блоков, ставали друг под друга, а не переносились на новую строчку

[скрин](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/04/08/0014/0699/975547/47/2bbe188e54.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Обекты должны быть блочные или инлайн блок, также у них должна быть занята высота и ширина.
display: flex;
flex-direction: row; - в строку
flex-direction: column; - в колонку